# I encountered the problem that python cannot find carla_bridge.core when using carla_apollo_bridge3.0

Tags: carla

The URL of carla_apollo_bridge3.0 is as follows：[carla_apollo_bridge](https://github.com/guardstrikelab/carla_apollo_bridge)
The usage tutorial is as follows：[readme](https://github.com/guardstrikelab/carla_apollo_bridge/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md)
I completed most of the build normally, but something went wrong when I got to the last step.
When I used this command to start bridge,

```
python main.py
```

I encountered this error：

```
root@in-dev-docker:/apollo/modules/carla_bridge/carla_bridge# python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    from carla_bridge.core.actor_factory import ActorFactory
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'carla_bridge.core'
```

I tried use pip3

```
root@in-dev-docker:/apollo/modules/carla_bridge/carla_bridge# pip3 install carla_bridge
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement carla_bridge (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for carla_bridge
root@in-dev-docker:/apollo/modules/carla_bridge/carla_bridge# pip3 install carla_bridge.core
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement carla_bridge.core (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for carla_bridge.core
```